# Bluetooth and Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have bluetooth headphones and have dual boot windows and Ubuntu, when I set the headphones to work with one OS, it stops working with the other, I have to delete and reconnect. I'm more interested in why this happens than solving it. Is the bluetooth card address the same in both OS and this creates a problem.

Headphones are Bose QCii, ubuntu is 21.04, but same issue with 20.04

Comment: Probably the bluetooth drivers for your headphones need to change the configuration of the bluetooth card in order to work with the headphones. As the drivers are dependent on the OS, each OS has to make the changes again to configure the headset. I guess if you boot the same OS multiple times after another, the headset works without reinstalling?

Comment: Thanks @DarkDiamond yes so it will work with Ubuntu each time I boot, but then if I try it on windows I need to delete the connection and make a new one, an that processes breaks the ubuntu connection